# ElasticSearch TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, firebase, server, full-text-search

I am writing server code that listens for search requests on the firebase database and return the search result.  This is the code that indexes the data from Firebase Database to Elastic Search.  Is this the correct way to index data?

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var ElasticClient = require('elasticsearchclient');

// listen for changes to Firebase data
var client = new ElasticClient({host:'localhost',port:9200});

firebase.initializeApp({
    serviceAccount: {
        ...
    },

    databaseURL: "https://searchserver.firebaseio.com/"
})

var db = firebase.database();
var ref = db.ref("realtime");

ref.on('child_added', upsert);
ref.on('child_changed', upsert);
ref.on('child_removed', remove);

function upsert(snap) {
    client.index({
        index: 'firebase',
        type: 'users',
        id: snap.key,
        body: snap.val()
    }, function (err, response) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error indexing " + error)
        }
    });
}

function remove(snap) {
    client.delete({
        index: 'firebase',
        type: 'users',
        id: snap.key
    }, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error deleting user : " + error);
        }
    });
}
```

This is the error message.

```
TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters.
at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:50:11)
at Object.exports.request (http.js:31:10)
at ElasticSearchCall.exec (C:\Users\jojo\Documents\readouts-search\readouts-server\node_modules\elasticsearchclient\lib\elasticsearchclient\calls\elasticSearchCall.js:45:26)
at ElasticSearchClient.createCall (C:\Users\jojo\Documents\readouts-search\readouts-server\node_modules\elasticsearchclient\lib\elasticsearchclient\elasticSearchClient.js:28:14)
at ElasticSearchClient.index (C:\Users\jojo\Documents\readouts-search\readouts-server\node_modules\elasticsearchclient\lib\elasticsearchclient\calls\core.js:37:17)
at upsert (C:\Users\jojo\Documents\readouts-search\readouts-server\readouts-server.js:28:12)
at C:\Users\jojo\Documents\readouts-search\readouts-server\node_modules\firebase\database-node.js:146:375
at Qb (C:\Users\jojo\Documents\readouts-search\readouts-server\node_modules\firebase\database-node.js:43:165)
at nc (C:\Users\jojo\Documents\readouts-search\readouts-server\node_modules\firebase\database-node.js:31:216)
at oc (C:\Users\jojo\Documents\readouts-search\readouts-server\node_modules\firebase\database-node.js:30:701)
```

Value of snap.val()

```
{ '5Nyu7Px7vNYGizJqlyGHhAfnvwu2':
{ allOwnerVideos: 'none',
 allRatedVideos: 'none',
 email: 'iron@man.com',
 favorite_category:
  { fifth: 'Business',
    first: 'Sports',
    fourth: 'Biography',
    second: 'Sci-Fi',
    seventh: 'Action and Adventure',
    sixth: 'Art',
    third: 'Satire' },
 name: 'iron',
 personalmessage: 'man',
 profileimage: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/readoutsa75e0.appspot.com/o/ProfilePictures%2F_5Nyu7Px7vNYGizJqlyGHhAfnvwu2.jpg?alt=media&token=743dbd6a-985c-4481-9d63-4ed30e8703a9' },
 '6bt3EqdWyfQ3ksEdy9BTyYvQK4F3'
```

Comment: Please share what `snap.val()` looks like? Looks like there's a problem escaping certain characters.

Comment: works fine for me with AWS Elastic Search service.

Comment: Hmm, thank you.  I wonder if it's because of my locahost.